# Hide or removing a menubar of tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu

I can set my menu with the following instruction:

```
my_tk.config(menu=my_menu_bar)
```

But, How do I remove it or hide it completely?

```
my_tk.config(menu=None)
```

doesn't work :-(

Comment: have you tried replacing it with an instance of a `Menu` that doesn't have anything in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

submenu = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Submenu", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="Option 1")
submenu.add_command(label="Option 2")
submenu.add_command(label="Option 3")

def remove_func():
    emptyMenu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=emptyMenu)

remove_button = Button(root, text="Remove", command=remove_func)
remove_button.pack()
```

What's different:
in

```
def remove_func():
```

created an empty menu

```
emptyMenu = Menu(root)
```

and replaced it with the current menu (`menubar`)

```
root.config(menu=emptyMenu)
```

Comment: I will select this answer as THE answer, because it answer better the Hide part of my question :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Additionally, you can add a show functionality that contains a new menu with its submenus each of which has items.

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, I know this question is old and has an accepted answer but this worked for me on tkinter version 8.6 Python 3

```
my_tk.config(menu="")
```

For some reason an empty string works but not `None`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

submenu = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Submenu", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="Option 1")
submenu.add_command(label="Option 2")
submenu.add_command(label="Option 3")

def remove_func():
    menubar.delete(0, END)

remove_button = Button(root, text="Remove", command=remove_func)
remove_button.pack()
```

?