# How to remove "Python" from tk menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple Python desktop application using tkinter. I want to have "Release" and "Module" in my dropdown menu. The issue is, there is always an extra menu -"Python" in it. How do I remove that? (My code is below):

```
root = Tk()

myLabel =Label(root, text="Welcome!")
myLabel.pack()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
myButton = Button(root, text="Build DashBoard",command=myClick)
myButton.pack()
subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Release",menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Now Project.....",command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="New.....",command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=doNothing)
```

[image]

Comment: Try using - menu.delete(0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide or removing a menubar of tkinter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556387/hide-or-removing-a-menubar-of-tkinter-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it works

```
menu.delete(0)
```

for more reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556387/hide-or-removing-a-menubar-of-tkinter-in-python)